# Doesn't create a txt file java

Tags: java, file-io

```
PrintStream out;
try {
   out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream( "C:\\RandomWalkResultater.txt", true));
   System.setOut(out);
```

It's not creating the txt file in C:
Btw this works fine in a mac using:

```
PrintStream out;
try {
     out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/Volumes/DATA/Desktop/RandomWalkResultater.txt", true));
            System.setOut(out);
```

Comment: Do you close the Stream when you're done?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not sure what you mean, so probably not :(

Comment: after the catch add a `finally{out.close();}` this will close the stream either if you didn't get any exceptions or if catched one.

Comment: It's difficult to close the stream in any case, but the OS do it for us, it's not a problem when redirected to stdout and stderr.

Comment: @Templar if I do that, the out. gives this error "The local variable out may not have been initialized"

Comment: Copy/Paste my code which doesn't use variable at all...

Comment: @Aubin It didn't work. Still doesn't create the TxT file.. It's like the path doesn't exits, if I type this in "/Volumes/DATA/Desktop/RandomWalkResultater.txt" it does it on my mac without problems. Win8 sucks

Comment: A google search relative to Windows 8 and user rights returns many similar problems. Even powered user, some folders remains protected. Try to change the path to a "end-user" folder.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works well for me

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd.HH-mm" );
final String log = "C:/" + sdf.format( new Date());
System.setOut( new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream( log + "-out.txt" ), true ));
System.setErr( new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream( log + "-err.txt" ), true ));
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to close your Stream after use, and this is best to do in a finally block, so that it is almost guaranteed to be done. Also, when you declare your out variable, set it initially to `null` so that the compiler will see that you do set it to *something* before using it. Do something like so:

```
  // declare your Stream variable and initialize to null
  PrintStream out = null; 
  try {
     // FILE_STREAM_PATH is a String constant to your output path
     out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_STREAM_PATH, true));
     System.setOut(out);

     // use your Stream here

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     // ***** close the Stream in the finally block *****
     if (out != null) {
        out.close();
     }
  }
```

Comment: It's not realistic with several thread, a GUI and poor old legacy code which call exit(x) in case of fatal error...

Answer (score -1):

Try using `new File("C:\\RandomWalkResultater.txt").createNewFile()` if you want to create the file.